# Error: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, executable

So this is a pretty weird issue I have. To be succinct I can compile my C++ code on Visual Studio Code   for the most recent compilation using Visual Studio Code but the executable does not run giving the error message
"Error: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1 char:1

- ./assignement_5.exe
- 

At line:1 char:1

- ./assignement_5.exe
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed"
  ```

BUT the old executables I have from previous codes ru with no problem.

So new executables from new codes do not work but old executables do work. What has changed?

I installed Fortran with loads of packages recently. I also did have to change my environmental variable in this process and install another g++ package which I am scared might have changed something to my visual studio installation.
Please tell me if you need any more information and if you have any idea of what to do cause I am completely lost.
Kind regards,
Ma_Boi

Comment: I believe that means the executable does not exist in the current folder.

Comment: ***What has changed?*** Maybe the build failed. Maybe your antivirus deleted your executable just after it was created.

Comment: The build runs successfully as written in the terminal and the executable seems to be very much in my folder...

Comment: But I do have to say that I feel that the code compiles way faster that it use to and this is the message it gives: "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\cpp.exe" -g C:\Users\eliot\projects\week_6-7\assignement_5.cpp -o C:\Users\eliot\projects\week_6-7\assignement_5.exe     seems to be different to what it was before but I am really not sure about that...

Comment: does it work when you do all the stuff from the command line? Clear the folder of all generated stuff (*.o, *.exe)

Comment: hmm interesting it gives me this message when compiling with the command prompt: The program or feature assignement_5.exe cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows version is available.